# How can I trace MAC address of not asosciated devices in my WiFi network?

Tags: wireless, mac-address, user-tracking

I'm looking for hints to solve my problem.
I would like to trace all devices that are in my surroundings.
I know how do it when someone already access to my WiFi network, but I'm also interested to see all other devices.
My idea is to trace mac address of all devices (associated and not associated to my AP).
I assume that mac address is broadcasted by any device with WiFi network card independently of connection to the WiFi network and is primal for network card.
I also assume that I can buy AP that can "see" it and finally log to the file.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Use AirMon-NG part of the AirCrack suite though you'll only see MAC of devices which are probing, broadcasting or connected to an existing network.